# autocomplete with thinking sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

when I search for the second word the result mismatch 
for example 'web '
the result

```
["WEB MEDIA ","CREATIV WEB ","WEB SERVICES TECHNOLOGIES","iDURAR WEB AGENCY","WEB CREATION","DEV WEB SOLUTION","BIG WEB DZ","AMANA SITE WEB"]
```

but for 'web m'
the result

```
["VOISINAGE PC","DELTA SOFT","MMCOMPUTING ETS","MICROPROZ","PORTIDEE","LATICODE","CYBER WEB SERVICES","SIEGE SOCIAL","EL DALIL YALAOUI ET CIE - SIEGE COMMERCIAL""IMA"]
```

iI try all examples in the internet

```
ruby
@suggestions = Form.search(params[:term]).map{ |x| x[:name]}
```

SELECT * FROM `form_core` WHERE MATCH('web m') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 LIMIT 0, 20
  Sphinx  Found 23 results

Comment: How exactly do you want your search to function? If you put in two words do you want both to be matched or just one?

Comment: @Mark yes i want both to be matched .
the problem is when I add the second word the result match only the second word

Comment: Is `name` the only field you have? Or does your Form index have other fields involved? Also: which versions of Sphinx and Thinking Sphinx are you using?

Comment: Hello @pat I resolve the problem by add  ^ and * and remove stars
```ruby
ThinkingSphinx.search('^' + params[:term] + '*', options)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the best result by adding ^ and * to

```
ThinkingSphinx.search('^' + params[:term] + '*', options)
```

and it's ok

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
search_terms = params[:term].split(' ')
@suggestions = []
Form.all.each do |instance|
  next unless (search_terms - instance.name.join(' ')).empty?
  @suggestions << instance
end
```

This will create an array of search terms, and an array of words your form instance has for names. It then checks if every element in the search_terms array is present in the array of words present in the form's name, and adds it to `@suggestions` if every word is present.

Comment: it's bad solution where is the sphinx seach ?